# MATLAB: How to apply the colfilt command

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, filtering

I have an image of 768 by 1024 pixels. I want to perform an order statistical filter such as the minimum and maximum on this image.  To do this, I would like to employ the `colfilt` function with a 5 by 5 sliding window to do a minimum filter.  In other words:

```
OP = colfilt(IP, [5 5], 'sliding', @min);
```

However, I got this error message:

> ??? Error using ==> reshape To RESHAPE the number of elements must not
>       change.
>
> Error in ==> colfilt at 183 b(i*mb+brows,j*nb+bcols) = ...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `colfilt` isn't working for you.   I did some tests on using `colfilt` and it seems to be working on my end.  Can you provide a link or somewhere where I can download the image and test it?

In the meantime, what you can do instead to accomplish (pretty much) the same thing is to try using `im2col` to take each sliding window neighbourhood and place these into separate columns.  After that, take the minimum of each of the columns, then reconstruct it back into a matrix by doing `col2im`.  As such, try doing:

1. Do `IP2 = im2col(IP, [5 5]);`
2. Then do `OP = min(IP2);`
3. Once you're done, do: `OP2 = col2im(OP, [5 5], [768 1024]);`

`OP2` will thus contain your (min.) filtered image.  Bear in mind that this will contain a cropped version of the image where some pixels along the borders were eliminated to ensure that the filtering mask completely fits inside the image.  As such, your output will be a 766 x 1022 image as your mask was 5 x 5.  If you want to avoid this, consider **padding** your matrix along the borders so that you can get the same sized output at the end.  Because your mask is 5 x 5, you will have a 2 pixel border around the image that remains unprocessed to ensure that the mask stays fully contained in the image.  As such, try doing this before you do Steps #1 - #3:

```
IPPad = padarray(IP, [2 2], 'replicate');
```

The `replicate` option will simply copy those pixels along the borders of the original image around the borders of the padded image.  This will create a 2 pixel border surrounding your image.  Other options include `circular` and `symmetric`.  You can also not specify the `replicate` flag if you want to pad your borders entirely with zero (zero-padding).

Hope this helps!